# redirect to another page not working (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a register form in nodejs. Once I save the user to a database and i try to redirect to another html page I get an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0". Could anyone help me out with it.If i console.log the user it appears, but if i try to redirect it doesn't work I make use of a express router to to route my requests.

[image]

Here is my code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const { registerValidation } = require("../models/validation");
const User = require("../models/user");
var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(appDir + "/public/index.html");
});
router.get("/homepage", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(appDir + "/public/homepage.html");
});

router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(appDir + "/public/register.html");
});

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
const { error } = await registerValidation.validate(req.body);
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error);

let emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

if (emailExist) {
 return res.status(400).send({ message: "Email already exists" });
}
let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

let newUser = new User({
 firstName: req.body.firstName,
 lastName: req.body.lastName,
 email: req.body.email,
 password: hashedPassword,
});

try {
 let savedUser = await newUser.save();
 res.redirect("/homepage");
} catch (err) {
 return res.status(400).send(err);
}
});

module.exports = router;
```

Home page Router

```
router.get("/homepage", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(appDir + "/public/homepage.html");
});
```

homepage.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is homepage</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Register Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/register.css" />
    <title>Register</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="register-container">
        <header class="header-text">
          Register today to become a movie nerd!!
          <hr />
        </header>

        <form method="POST" name="register-form" id="register-form">
          <div class="register-form">
            <div class="name-field">
              <div class="name-input-container">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="firstName"
                  class="form-input"
                  id="firstName"
                  value="Kevin"
                  required
                  placeholder="First Name "
                />
              </div>
              <div class="name-input-container">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="lastName"
                  class="form-input"
                  id="lastName"
                  placeholder="Last Name "
                  required
                  value="Rodrigues"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="email-input-container">
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                class="form-input"
                id="email"
                placeholder="Email "
                value="kevinrodrigues43@gmail.com"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="password-field">
              <div class="password-input-container">
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  class="form-input"
                  id="password"
                  value="Kevinr78"
                  required
                  placeholder="Passsword "
                />
              </div>
              <div class="name-input-container">
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="confirmPassword"
                  class="form-input"
                  id="C_password"
                  placeholder="Confirm Password "
                  value="Kevinr78"
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="error">
              <p id="error"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="register-button">
              <button type="button" id="register-button">Register</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script>
      document
        .getElementById("register-button")
        .addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
          let formData = validation(e);
          let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/register", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            },
          })
            .then((data) => {
              return data.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
              console.log(data);
              const { message } = data;
              document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = message;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = err;
            });
        });
      function validation(e) {
        let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        let lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        let firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        let confirmPassword = document.getElementById("C_password").value;
        let emailRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$";
        let error = "";

        if (
          firstName == "" ||
          lastName == "" ||
          password == "" ||
          confirmPassword == "" ||
          email == ""
        ) {
          error += "<p>PLease fill all the fields</p>";
        }
        if (firstName.length < 2 || lastName.length < 2) {
          error += "<p>Length of name field is minimum 2 characters</p>";
        }
        /*  if (password != confirmPassword) {
          error += "<p>Password Don't match</p>";
        } */
        if (!email.match(emailRegex)) {
          error += "<p>Invalid Email</p>";
        }

        if (error == "") {
          return { lastName, password, firstName, email, confirmPassword };
        } else {
          document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = error;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />

    <title>Movies Bay</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <nav class="nav-container">
        <div class="brand-name">
          <h3 href="#">Movies Bay</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-items">
          <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="/login"> Login </a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="/register"> Register </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="main-content">
        <h2 id="intro-text"></h2>
        <br />
        <h4>Your one stop destination for movies</h4>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p class="text-1">Made By Kevin Rodrigues</p>
        <p class="text-2">&#169; 2020-2021</p>
      </footer>
    </section>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed) {
        let element = document.getElementById(destination);
        element.style.fontSize = "4.5em";
        var i = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
          element.innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
          i++;
          if (i > message.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }, speed);
      }

      printLetterByLetter("intro-text", "Welcome to Movies bay", 100);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add your other html files?

Comment: @zx01 Have added other html files. The register and index html files

Comment: `return data.json()` is trying to parse JSON, but it was fed something like `<!DOCTPYE html><html>etc...`. There is a _token_ (character) that is _unexpected_ (it didn't expect a <) _at position 0_ (the first character). HTML is not JSON, so you get an error. Check your network tab/logs what's going wrong.

Comment: @RickN Okay thanks, i'll try that out . Also, so after getting the response back from the  server and in the second then() block if i redirect it should work right?

Comment: Is the problem that your fetch() call is getting sent the homepage (as per res.redirect("/homepage");) - but your handler is expecting JSON. You can't replace the entire document in response to a fetch call - you would need to do a more traditional form submission to do that I think.

Comment: @Woody, Actually  I had used a fetch call in register.html and I was sending an HTML page back as a response from the server which caused the JSON error. So I just performed the redirect once I got a response back from the server that the user is saved.